# Prioritise favourites in Rails SQL query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a difficult query problem in Ruby on Rails. The setup is:

- A User model
- A Contact model, which is a simple join model between 2 users and has 2 fields, user_id and friend_id

I want to perform a search which returns all users matching some search criteria, but prioritises the contacts such that they are returned first. My query uses a limit and offset to select a subset of users, therefore I need to do this as part of the SQL query rather than sort the records after the objects are returned.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
@users = User.limit(@limit).offset(@offset)

# Some search code...
@users = @users.where(....)

# Find the current user's contacts' IDs
contact_ids = current_user.contacts.collect{|a| a.friend_id}

# Order the results such that contacts are first
@users = @users.order( some function to prioritise records in the contact_ids list over the others )

# Return the query
render json: @users.all
```

Many thanks

Comment: Why are these libraries thought to make sql work easier?

Comment: Could you generate both results and combine them?  Something like `@users = @users.where("user_id IN (?)",contact_ids) + @users.where("user_id NOT IN (?)",contact_ids)`.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I think this would return both queries fully then put them together. This wouldn't work since I want the query to return the entire users table, but to select which bit I want using offset and limit.

Comment: Drew - if you know how to do this in SQL it would be a big help...

Comment: I know how to do it but ya probably want it wrapped in your objects

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Do it as if there was no ror involved? Then `show create table tbl ` output for relevant tables

Comment: I don't know how to do it as if there was no ROR involved. This is a bit beyond my SQL skills - perhaps you could share an example?

Comment: Fortunately for me ror is never involved. Do you know how to execute a mysql command in ror and play with the resultset?

Comment: Yes, that's fairly straightforward - I'm just not very good at constructing the complex queries

Comment: See my comment 4 up from this. Tables please

Answer (score 0):

You could use `order_by` for this purpose, assuming `favorited` is a binary or integer field on the `Contact` model:

```
@users = @users.order_by('favorited DESC')
```

**Note:** `DESC` stands for "descending." This will usually be appropriate here for a binary field, because `true` will take on the value of 1, and `false` will take on the value of 0. If you instead need to sort in ascending order (smallest to largest), you can use `ASC` instead of `DESC`.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. Actually I want to order by the _existence_ of a contact model. I want the query to return the entire database of users (with offset and limit of course) but to prioritise those who are in your contacts. I suppose I could create a contact model between every user in the database but it seems quite inefficient...

Comment: Ahh, in that case, I'm guessing you're going to have to do two queries. This would be very challenging to do in a single statement.

Comment: It's certainly a challenge - but I reckon with all the ingenuity on StackOverflow it must be possible!